# the factor ring $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle3-i\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I can't understand this :if I have :

the factor ring $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle3-i\rangle$ and am asked to find elements zero in this ,they are $0,3-i,i(3-i),(3-i)+i(3-i)$.

But I can't understand this and I feel they should be of form:$0,3-i,i+(3-i),(3-i)+i(3-i)$.because the cosets of ring will be like :$\langle3-i\rangle$+$\mathbb Z[i]$.

please help Where am I wrong?

Comment: No coset looks like $A + \mathbb Z[i]$ for any set $A$. Rather, cosets look like $a + \mathbb Z[i]\cdot\langle3-i\rangle$ for some element $a$.

Comment: @Lubin but coset look similar to way we define them in group..Please explain how you came with this...

Comment: Because if $H\subset G$, subgroup of an additive group, the cosets look like $a+H$, with $a$ running through the various elements of $G$. In your case, the subgroup is the set of all multiples of $3-i$ by elements of $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 4):

The zero element of the quotient ring $R/I$ (where $R$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal of $R$) is simply $I$. Here, it means all multiples of $3-i$. In other words, $\{z(3-i)\mid z \in \mathbf{Z}[i]\}$.

Comment: suppose I had $\mathbb Z[i]/(3-i)$ instead of $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle3-i\rangle$ then what should have zero  elemnets looked like...

Comment: As far as I know, those two notations mean the same thing (the quotient of $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ by the principal ideal generated by $3-i$).